# Trying to create a script for HighScore in my Unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create my own game, according to the guide from YouTube, all the errors that arose, I successfully fixed myself, also made my own improvements that were not in the guide, but here I'm stuck. I'm trying to create a script that saves and displays HighScore. I'm doing this based on my Score script, which is working successfully.

!!!One script is assigned to the score text, the other to the HighScore text!!!

Don't throw tomatoes, this is my first more or less serious project on Unity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class GameScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    TMP_Text ScoreTextUI;
    int score;

    public int Score
    {
        get
        {
            return this.score;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.score = value;
            UpdateScoreTextUI();
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        ScoreTextUI = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
    }

    
    void UpdateScoreTextUI()
    {
        string scoreStr = string.Format("{0:0000000}", score);
        ScoreTextUI.text = scoreStr;
    }
}
```

My attempts at writing a HighScore script look like this, but it doesn't work. The HighScore is displayed as 0000000 at the beginning, as it should be, but it does not change.

!!!One script is assigned to the score text, the other to the HighScore text!!!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class GameHighScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject scoreUIText;
    TMP_Text HighScoreTextUI;
    int highscore;
    float scoreforhighscore;

    public int HighScore
    {
        get
        {
            return this.highscore;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.highscore = value;
            //UpdateHighScoreTextUI();
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        scoreUIText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ScoreTextTag");
        HighScoreTextUI = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
        scoreforhighscore = scoreUIText.GetComponent<GameScore>().Score;
        highscore = (int)scoreforhighscore;
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("scoreforhighscore") >= highscore) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("scoreforhighscore", highscore);
        }
        string HighscoreStr = string.Format("{0:0000000}", highscore);
        HighScoreTextUI.text = HighscoreStr;
        //HighScoreTextUI.text = "" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("scoreforhighscore").ToString();
    }
    
    //void UpdateHighScoreTextUI()
    //{
        //string HighscoreStr = string.Format("{0:0000000}", highscore);
        //HighScoreTextUI.text = HighscoreStr;
    //}
}
```

Also, my script for the enemy looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour
{   
    GameObject scoreUIText;
    [SerializeField] float speed;
    public GameObject Explosion;

    void Start()
    {
        scoreUIText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ScoreTextTag");

    }


    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 position = transform.position;
        position = new Vector2(position.x, position.y - speed * Time.deltaTime);
       
        transform.position = position;

        //screen limits 
        Vector2 min = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0,0)); //bottom-left point corner of the screen
        if (transform.position.y < min.y) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) 
    {
        //Detect collision
        if((col.tag == "PlayerShipTag") || (col.tag == "PlayerBulletTag")) 
        {
            PlayExplosion();

            //add 100 points
            scoreUIText.GetComponent<GameScore>().Score += 50;

            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    //explosion func
    void PlayExplosion() 
    {
        GameObject explosion =(GameObject)Instantiate(Explosion);
        explosion.transform.position = transform.position;
    }
}
```

Also, my GameManagerScript looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject playButton;
    public GameObject playerShip;
    public GameObject enemySpawner;
    public GameObject mediumEnemyspawner;
    public GameObject gameOver;
    public GameObject scoreUIText;
    public GameObject TimeCounter;
    public GameObject GameTitle;
    
    public enum GameManagerState
    {
        Opening,
        Gameplay,
        GameOver,
    }

    GameManagerState GMState;

    void Start()
    {
        GMState = GameManagerState.Opening;
    }

//update GM State
    void UpdateGameManagerState()
    {
        switch (GMState) 
        {
            case GameManagerState.Opening:
                gameOver.SetActive(false);
                GameTitle.SetActive(true);
                playButton.SetActive(true);
                break;

            case GameManagerState.Gameplay:
                scoreUIText.GetComponent<GameScore>().Score = 0;
                playButton.SetActive(false);
                GameTitle.SetActive(false);
                playerShip.GetComponent<PlayerControl>().Init(); //player visible, lives init
                enemySpawner.GetComponent<EnemySpawner>().ScheduleEnemySpawn();
                mediumEnemyspawner.GetComponent<MediumEnemySpawner>().ScheduleEnemySpawn();
                TimeCounter.GetComponent<TimeCounter>().StartTimeCounter();
                break;

            case GameManagerState.GameOver:
                TimeCounter.GetComponent<TimeCounter>().StopTimeCounter();
                enemySpawner.GetComponent<EnemySpawner>().UnScheduleEnemySpawn();
                mediumEnemyspawner.GetComponent<MediumEnemySpawner>().UnScheduleEnemySpawn();
                gameOver.SetActive(true);

                Invoke("ChangeToOpeningState", 5f); //reboot after .. sec
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SetGameManagerState(GameManagerState state) 
    {
        GMState = state;
        UpdateGameManagerState();
    }

//play button func
    public void StartGamePlay() 
    {
        GMState = GameManagerState.Gameplay;
        UpdateGameManagerState();
    }

//change state to opening
public void ChangeToOpeningState() 
{
    SetGameManagerState(GameManagerState.Opening);
}
}
```

Comment: you dont seem to save the score to playerprefs?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be storing your score anywhere, I slightly modified your code below so that it sets your highscore in your PlayerPrefs whenever your current score exceeds the previous highscore

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class GameScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    TMP_Text ScoreTextUI;
    int score;
    int highScore;
    public int Score
    {
        get
        {
            return this.score;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.score = value;
            UpdateScoreTextUI();
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        ScoreTextUI = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("scoreforhighscore");
    }

    
    void UpdateScoreTextUI()
    {
        string scoreStr = string.Format("{0:0000000}", score);
        ScoreTextUI.text = scoreStr;
        if (score > highScore) // This is what you were missing
        {
            highScore = score;  
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("scoreforhighscore", highScore);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I split Score and HighScore into two scripts as I wrote above? Maybe im stupid, sorry. I have one script is assigned to the score text, the other to the HighScore text.

Comment: By modifying your normal script to the one I provided your HighScore script should work without any modifications (assuming the HighScore script is running AFTER the normal score script), the only thing you were missing was actually setting the high score in the PlayerPrefs

Comment: HighScore still shows as 0000000 and does not update, normal Score works correctly. The Enemy script has the number of points on a hit, should I change something here? Sorry for my weirdness, I've been solving this problem for too long and maybe I'm not seeing the obvious. (I added the script for the enemy to the post)

Comment: I'd suggest adding a `Debug.Log()` somewhere in your HighScore script to make sure its actually running correctly

Comment: Can you please modify my code again? I have never experienced Debug.Log() before. Now I have error CS1501: No overload for method 'Log' takes 0 arguments. What arguments should I use?

Comment: `Debug.Log()` is a way to log a message in the unity console during runtime, in the parentheses you'd enter whatever it is you want to log, eg: `Debug.Log("Test");` would print "Test" in the console when that line runs, in your case you could type in `Debug.Log(highscore);` and it will print out the value of `highscore` at that moment in time.

Comment: Debug.Log(highscore); always 0

Comment: That leads me to believe that its not accessing your `GameScore` script correctly, are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: No, there's no errors in the console. Only yellow Warning icons about The character used for Underline is not available in font asset ^_^ It's always been there, and as far as I'm concerned, it doesn't interfere with anything.

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly are you running the HighScore script?

Comment: can u check my GameManager script, i added it to the post, maybe i should change it somehow?